# The method 'BlocProvider' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, provider

I'm trying to to use Bloc but my BlocProvider return an error:

```
The method 'BlocProvider' isn't defined for the type '_MyAppState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'BlocProvider'.
```

I cant find anywhere about solving this issue.

Here's the code i'm working with

```
import 'package:app_13/post_cubit.dart';
import 'package:app_13/post_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocProvider<PostsCubit> (
        create: (context) => PostsCubit(),
        child: PostsView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And added flutter_bloc in pub.yaml

```
  bloc: ^8.1.0
```

What am i doing wrong? Why is BlocProvider not recognized?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) package instead

It has the additional classes such as `BlocProvider`

Comment: Please mark the question as solved if the problem is solved

Answer (score 3):

For this problem use "import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

use the above in the import section and your error should be gone. I hope it helps :)